# Problema con ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

El programa es bastante sencillo, x, y, z son Doubles que se están actualizando constantemente y guardo los 2 primeros valores de cada uno en un ArrayList y luego los quiero mostrar por pantalla (ya se que podía haber hecho un for pero copiar y pegar me fue más rápido para 6 valores XD)

```
            List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

            for(int i=0; i<5;i=+3){
                list.add(i,x);
                list.add(i+1,y);
                list.add(i+2,z);    
            }

                System.out.println(list.get(0));
                System.out.println(list.get(1));
                System.out.println(list.get(2));
                System.out.println(list.get(3));
                System.out.println(list.get(4));
                System.out.println(list.get(5));
```

El problema es que el programa se está ejecutando pero no muestra los valores por pantalla (no salta ninguna excepción, simplemente permanece en blanco y te da la opción de terminar el programa, por lo que sé que se está ejecutando)¿Algún fallo en el código?

Comment: Como dice @PHX255, tienes un bucle infinito: **`i` siempre vale 3**. La asignación `i=+3` no suma 3 a `i` le asigna 3 a `i`

Comment: for(int i=0; i<5;i+=3){ Error tipográfico.

Comment: Pff que tonto soy... perdón por la pregunta jaja Muchas gracias

Comment: A todos nos ha pasado. Toma café :). Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No logro entender muy bien el código ya que la explicación y el fragmento de código es un poco pobre y no conozco el sentido de ese for pero en lo que has aportado veo un error en la siguiente línea:

> for(int i=0; i<5;i=+3)

El operador `=+` es incorrecto, lo correcto sería `i+=3` que utiliza el operador += que equivaldría a `i=i+3`.

Has generado un bucle infinito estableciendo el valor de i siempre a 3.

Espero haber sido de ayuda, un saludo.

Comment: En caso de errores tipograficos lo correcto seria comentarlo en bajo la pregunta y reportar para su cierre como No relacionado > Error tipografico. Un saludo

Comment: Perdona, pretendía darle una explicación más extendida. Lo tendré en cuenta de ahora en adelante. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la verdad que es un fallo bastante estúpido la verdad, error de principiantes, con el tiempo espero no tenerlos

Comment: @Antonio siempre pasará, aun no siendo principiantes. Lo mejor es la calma y leer el codigo poco a poco explicando en alto todo lo que hace.  [El metodo del pato de goma](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_depuraci%C3%B3n_del_patito_de_goma) Un saludo